# implement Lazy property to async data in angulat service

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angular-services, subscription

I'm looking for the best way to have some kind of a **Lazy property** in Angular service, meaning - I would like to have a getter to a service property, and check - if the member is null, then I'll need to fetch data with an observable and set the member. and then return it (after is was set with the value).
This is how I did it now:

```typescript
    private _someDataItems : someDataItemType[];
    
    get someDataItems() : someDataItemType[]
    {
        if (!this._someDataItems)
        {
          this.getData().subscribe(result => //The get data return Observable<someDataItemType[]>
          {
            this._someDataItems = result;
            return this._someDataItems;
          });
        }
        else
        {
          return this._someDataItems;
        }
    }
    
    set someDataItems(value : someDataItemType[])
    {
      this._someDataItems = value;
    }
```

Is there a way of doing it ?

Comment: using `get` method for an asynchronous value is probably not a good idea, you may end up making too many requests to the server due to change detection

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to return an `Observable`.

```
private _someDataItems : someDataItemType[];

get someDataItems() : Observable<someDataItemType[]> {
    if (!this._someDataItems) {
      this.getData().pipe(map(result => //The get data return Observable<someDataItemType[]>
      {
        this._someDataItems = result;
        return this._someDataItems;
      }));
    }
    else
    {
      return of(this._someDataItems);
    }
}

set someDataItems(value : someDataItemType[])
{
  this._someDataItems = value;
}
```

Comment: 2 problems:
1. The getter and the setter should have the same type (now its Observable<someDataItemType[]> and someDataItemType[] - no go)
2. I would like to get the value itself - not the observable of it